# Unable to connect to the postgres DB from dockerized spring application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying containerize a spring boot application. For that I have added a Dockerfile in the parent directory of the application.
[Find the Dockerfile image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPxH2.png)

I did maven clean install with the below configuration.

```
  datasource:  
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/treefe"
    username: postgres
    password: 12345
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

When I try to run the container I am getting the error as shown. [check the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYUEx.png)

I have pulled the postgres image from dockerhub and ran the container.
Then I inspected the container and found the "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2" and added that in the configuration as shown.

```
  datasource:  
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/treefe"
    username: postgres
    password: 12345
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

When I try to run mvn clean install I am getting the error as shown.[check error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om2Uu.png)

From the error shown while running the container its clear that the jar is having localhost and that is why it is not able to connect. But if I try to change the connection properties details in the spring boot app and try to build the jar that is also failing. Please help me in fixing this. Thanks in advance.

Also find the Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
COPY target/*.jar testapp.jar
EXPOSE 8082
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "testapp.jar"]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... directly in the question body as [code block]**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Comment: The database location is different inside Docker vs. not.  Consider setting `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` as an environment variable in your Docker setup to the Docker-specific value.  The linked question has some examples.